Mapping Xlib to WinApi - how to check which keys are pressed
In my Linux application I can check which physical key is pressed using the following code:
int min_code = 0;
int max_code = 0;
char keys[32];

XDisplayKeycodes(dpy, &min_code, &max_code);
XQueryKeymap(dpy, keys);

for(int code = min_code; code < max_code; ++code)
{
    bool pressed = (keys[key_code / 8] & (1 << (key_code % 8))) != 0;     
}

How to achieve it using WinApi ? There is GetAsyncKeyState but it takes a virtual key argument. Moreover I don't have any idea how to iterate over all keys.

Try GetKeyboardState perhaps?

How can I detect if a regular enter key or numpad enter key has been pressed when using GetKeyboardState ? When handling WM_KEYDOWN I can detect it reading extended key flag from lParam.

This doesn't seem to be possible.

Change your application architecture from poll-based to event-based. It's the only model that works reliably.
